# Clang Cannot find CPP Files

Tags: c++, linux, clang, windows-subsystem-for-linux, undefined-reference

I am working on a project in which I am using WSL. Now, the issue is WSL needs to access CPP Project Files which are necessary for the linker. Previously, using this command(Ignore Flags) :-

```
clang++ -pthread -rdynamic -fopenmp -Wl,-rpath-link= -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--strip-discarded -Wl,--gc-sections -m64 -o ./main @main.rsp
```

I am getting this error:-

```
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/d/test/dll_so/out/../main/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `A::add1(int, int)'
```

But, when I changed my command(added path to CPP Files) :-

```
clang++ -pthread -rdynamic -fopenmp -Wl,-rpath-link= -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--strip-discarded -Wl,--gc-sections -m64 -o ./main @main.rsp /mnt/path/to/file.cpp
```

The linker is linking files. But, now the issue is I am having a very big project and I can't include the path to each CPP File(because that would be huge). What should I do now. I have been advised to create a makefile for it, but still confused on how to create it and use it. Please advice me to overcome this issue.

Comment: A build system (which can include makefiles) is the right solution.  Have you looked up how to write a makefile?

Comment: I looked in for that, but I am not sure on how to use that makefile with clang. Also, If you have any relevant reference for the process, can you share?

Comment: So why not ask specific question show your makefile and where you're having problems.  Please make sure you include a [mcve].